# LinUCB exploration-exploitation algorithm does not improve results over time

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning

I am trying to implement the Algorithm 1 given in the following paper. http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~lihong/pub/Li10Contextual.pdf

It is a typical exploration-exploitation algorithm. I have used the formula payoff=mean+ contant*standard deviation

First I ran the algorithm for a set of data I have and then I input one record from the dataset as the new input to see if it can predict the correct output. But it gave a wrong output so I gave a 0 reward and recalculated the mean and the standard deviation for that arm and continued with the algorithm. But each time it always returns the same arm. The mean does does not change as well.

Can someone explain to me how the mean and variation changes in this algorithm, when negative feedback is given? What must be the reason for me to alway get the same values?

I have used java to program. The code is as follows.

```
public void LINUCB(double[] newFeature, Arm arm) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "LINUCB");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Arm number " + arm.getArmID());
    if (arm.isNew()) {
        arm.setFeatureMatrix(getIdentityMatrix(ConstantValues.FEATURE_DIMENSION));
        arm.setResponseVector(new double[ConstantValues.FEATURE_DIMENSION]);
    }

    double[][] invertedFeatureMatrix = invert(arm.getFeatureMatrix());
    /**The response vector is [D*M][M].  it is the multiplication of tranpose of design matrix with the user feedback provided to each trial M*/
    //TODO use gradient descent here.
    double[] theta = getSquareMatrixColumnVectorMultiplication(invertedFeatureMatrix, arm.getResponseVector());        
    double meanPayOff = getRowVectorColumnVectorMultiplication(theta, newFeature);
    System.out.print(" meanPayOff " + meanPayOff);
    double standardDeviation = calculateUCB(newFeature, arm.getFeatureMatrix());
    System.out.print(" standardDeviation " + standardDeviation);
    double payOffForArm = meanPayOff + standardDeviation;
    System.out.print(" payOffForArm " + payOffForArm);
    if (payOffForArm > maxPayOff) {
        maxPayOff = payOffForArm;
        //armWithMaxPayOff = arm;
        //indexOfArmWithMaxPayOff = armArrayList.indexOf(arm);
        maxPayOffArmID = arm.getArmID();
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}

private double calculateUCB(double[] newFeature, double[][] featureMatrix) {
    double[] tmpColumVector = getSquareMatrixColumnVectorMultiplication(featureMatrix, newFeature);
    double tmpUCB = Math.sqrt(getRowVectorColumnVectorMultiplication(tmpColumVector, newFeature));
    double UCB = ConstantValues.ALPHA * tmpUCB;
    return UCB;
}
```

alpha is set to 0.3.

Comment: What language are you using? Could you please post your code here?

Comment: @GoBusto I think entire code is too long. But I have added to main methods. Hope you can get an idea about what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

For each round, LinUCB should be updating the Upper Confidence Bound of each arm based on its feature vector. I think you've implemented the algorithm incorrectly.

- You are passing a feature *and* an arm. You should be inspecting the features *of the* arm. Your newFeature argument is possibly independent of the arm and in which case, any correlation with the context (in this case, the feature vector) and the rewards is thrown out the window.
- Theta is used to compute an expected payoff assuming it is linear in the arm's feature vector with the coefficient vector theta. You're multiplying it with the newFeature vector when it should be with the arm's features.
- Unless it is a static variable, maxPayOff does not track the maximum UCB of all arms. It looks like a local variable within the conditional statement and thus, is not able to capture the maximum value of all arms.
- Lastly, check that your rewards are bounded between 0 and 1. It is a very common mistake and can cause weird behaviors.

Comment: Why do rewards bounded outside of 0 and 1 cause weird behaviors?

Comment: Regarding the first bullet point. Consider there to be another method that calls for each arm the LinUCB method. So that's why I am sending an arm. However, the newFeature reflects information about the user and it is the same feature used with all the arms. Is this incorrect? In the paper in Section 5.2.2. It is said that at trial t, each article has a seperate six-dimensional feature, which is the user feature.